# I need help identifying pins in the VAG ignition switch (Audi A3 2005)

Tags: ignition, audi, ignition-switch, a3

I need some help identifying the functions of the pins in my ignition switch. Some time ago my ignition switch started to malfunction. The issues I experienced were failing to switch into the desired mode and bouncing contacts (dash flickering). From the electronics point of view, I understand how undesirable flickering is and how the contact bouncing can over time cause damage or overheating of the terminal. I bought a replacement on eBay. Since it is a cheap variant I tested both to see if I get similar behaviour. I summarised the results below. I am 100% sure that pin 2 is +12V and I am almost certain what the functions of pins 1, 4, and 6 are but unsure about pins 3 and 5. If someone could confirm my assumptions or link some wiring diagrams for my vehicle I would be very grateful.

| Pin | Colour | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Starter |
| 2 | Purple | [12V] Main |
| 3 | Blue | Alarm OFF? |
| 4 | Green | Radio/Fan |
| 5 | Gray | Dome lights? |
| 6 | Yellow | Dash/Windows |

| New switch | Old switch |
| --- | --- |
| OFF (key out) | OFF (key out) |
| 2 - Nothing | 2-5 |
| Acc | Acc |
| 2-3-4 | 2-4 |
| ON | ON |
| 2-3-4-6 | 2-4-6 |
| Start | Start |
| 2-1-3-6 | 2-1-6 |
| OFF (key in) | OFF (key in) |
| 2-3-5 | 2-5 |